# Difference using strace with filters

Tags: linux, debugging, strace

What is the difference between using

```
strace -e open,read,write -p Process_ID
```

And

```
strace -e trace=open,read,write -p Process_ID
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no difference between them. `trace` is the default qualifier.